# Antimatroid that is not a partial order

Tags: order-theory

I am trying to understand the difference between an [antimatroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatroid) on a set and a partial order on a set.   [According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), an antimatroid is a generalization of partial order.  Thus, for some set $S$, there must be some antimatroid on $S$ for which there is no corresponding partial order in $S$.  Can someone give me an example of this?  What is the smallest $|S|$ where this can occur?

Comment: Seeing as most people (including me) don't know what an "antimatroid" is, perhaps, instead of linking to the Wikipedia page on partial orders (which most of us know about), you might link to a Wikipedia page which contains a [definition of antimatroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatroid#Definitions), or better yet, incorporate such a definition into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any matroid that comes from a partial order, the feasible sets are closed under intersections, since the lower sets in a poset are closed under intersections.  As an example where this fails, consider the antimatroid on the set $S=\{a,b,c\}$ in which every subset except $\{c\}$ is feasible.  This antimatroid cannot come from a partial order since $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ are feasible but their intersection is not.

Comment: And this, of course, is the smallest |S| where this can occur.